# Visual Studio 2015 Taskbar Title and Taskbar Previews Vague

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, usability

Visual Studio 2015 is nice and all, but it's very hard to use when having multiple instance open.  I have my Taskbar on the right, and this is what it looks like:

[image: Which project is which!?]

Any ideas on how to clear this up and make it easy to select the project I want, without hunting around?! Extensions welcome.

What do you guys do? Or should I utilize my memory powers more and remember which is which heh.

In VS 2013, there was VS Commands which helped, but they are yet to update it for VS2015...

One suggestion was to have my taskbar at the bottom of the screen. To me this is not feasible on a wide screen because you're losing even more height, where as you generally have more width that you can afford to lose...

I then tried it at the bottom, and it's even worse, since you fit less items in, and they group sooner, so you'd have to hover over VS before you can pick which one to switch to.

[image: Hmm even worse?]

## Update

As Sergey Vlasov mentioned, here is the window title change in action.  Very nice solution, thanks!

[image: Good solution]

Comment: You'll get an extra 8 characters if you keep your taskbar on the bottom. I might also suggest naming projects such that their first 12 characters are unique, then you won't run into the problem not matter where you put the taskbar.

Comment: On a wide screen it makes sense to me to have the task bar on the right, so that you're not making an already height limited display even more height limited if you get what I mean. Also, our solution names are fully name spaced, and that is a company standard, can't change that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create short abbreviations for your solutions using the [Visual Studio Window Title Changer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239) extension.